# PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 and AES encryption from java to swift

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, commoncrypto

```
   public static SecretKeySpec createKey(String secureKey, String secureId)
            throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        
        byte[] salt = secureId.getBytes();
        byte[] securekeyBytes = android.util.Base64.decode(secureKey, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        String finalKey = new String(securekeyBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(finalKey.toCharArray(), salt,
                Integer.valueOf(10000),
                Integer.valueOf(256));
       
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512")
                .generateSecret(spec);
        return new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES");
    }
```

This is my java code for encryption, I am trying to implement the same in swift, but not getting proper solution, so what is the equivalent code for this java code snippet in swift language?

```
    func createKey(secretKey: String, secretId: String) throws -> SymmetricKey {
        let salt = secretId.data(using: .utf8)!
        let accessKeyData = Data(base64Encoded: accessKey)!
        let finalKey = String(data: secretKeyData, encoding: .utf8)!
        
        let keyData = try! deriveKey(password: finalKey, salt: salt, iterations: 10000, keyLength: 256 / 8)
        
        return SymmetricKey(data: keyData)
    }

    func deriveKey(password: String, salt: Data, iterations: Int, keyLength: Int) throws -> Data {
        var derivedKeyData = Data(count: keyLength)
        let passwordData = password.data(using: .utf8)!
        
        let result = derivedKeyData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { derivedKeyBytes in
            salt.withUnsafeBytes { saltBytes in
                CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(CCPBKDFAlgorithm(kCCPBKDF2),
                                     password,
                                     passwordData.count,
                                     saltBytes,
                                     salt.count,
                                     CCPseudoRandomAlgorithm(kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA512),
                                     UInt32(iterations),
                                     derivedKeyBytes,
                                     keyLength)
            }
        }
        
        if result != kCCSuccess {
            throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: Int(result), userInfo: nil)
        }
        
        return derivedKeyData
    }
```

I used this method but its nit giving a proper expected result, so is there any way to achieve the same in simple code format

Comment: Does the Base64 decoding of `secureKey` provide a UTF8 compliant byte sequence, so that UTF-8 decoding of `securekeyBytes` is possible without corruption? Post test data.

Comment: Yep, undoubtedly this has to do with the character encodings used. Could in principle also be the salt as the character encoding is not indicated during `getBytes`. Stepping through the pragram and comparing values would be the way. Note that Java, and maybe swift too have the bad habbit of simply dropping characters if they aren't known (in Java you can remedy that by using a real `CharsetDecoder`).

Comment: @Topaco Oh, I forgot: PBKDF2 in Java uses the lower 8 bits of each 16 bit character. coder hard probably has to encode the password to UTF-16 and then take the lower bits. "Different PBE mechanisms may consume different bits of each password character. For example, the PBE mechanism defined in PKCS #5 looks at only the low order 8 bits of each character, whereas PKCS #12 looks at all 16 bits of each character." Yuk.

Comment: You could first use a *transparent* password like `String finalKey = "123456789"` to check if both codes give the same result and to eliminate a possible source of error for further troubleshooting (if the problem persists  even then). @MaartenBodewes - Java's PBKDF2 encodes the `char[]` internally with UTF-8 (which can be checked e.g. with the BC implementation, which uses a `byte[]` instead of a `char[]`, in conjunction with appropriate codepoints).

Comment: @Topaco Don't check against BC, it's right there in the JavaDoc, isn't it? [Here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/0712adc2dd2e61f9409dd5fd210bc6a8c5b8276d/src/java.base/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/PBES2Core.java#L261) you go: `passwdChars[i] = (char) (passwdBytes[i] & 0x7f);`. I *think* the highest bit is always zero, so in that sense the 8 bit part in the documentation is correct. Of course, this means ASCII, and ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. I think there were some side channel considerations going into this, but it is really stupid none-the-less.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - *...Don't check against BC...* Why? A comparison with a PBKDF2 implementation where the encoding can be chosen is a pretty good test! Also, according to debugging/stack `key` is a `PBKDF2KeyImpl` instance and the Utf8 encoding takes place in [`getPasswordBytes()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/0712adc2dd2e61f9409dd5fd210bc6a8c5b8276d/src/java.base/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/PBKDF2KeyImpl.java#L71).

Comment: Oh, sheesh, "this is my Java code for encryption", is Android of course. Hmm, then it depends on the provider, could well be BC. Still wondering if we didn't drop any characters in the process though.

Comment: @coderhard Sorry for the long discussion. Please generate intermediate values for all input variables and make sure you only enter ASCII into PBKDF2 because otherwise all bets are off.